# How to get a list of lambda arns?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In AWS cloudformation template is there a way to get a list of lambda arns similar to how you can get sns arns?

```
"Ref" : "AWS::NotificationARNs"
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html

Comment: is [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#arn-syntax-lambda) what you're looking for ?

Comment: yes a list of those arns or function-names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a CloudFormation template, you can use [`GetAtt`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html) to get the ARN of a specific Lambda.  Example:

```
"Resources": {
  "mylambda": {
    "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
    "Properties": {
      ...
    }
  }
},
"Outputs": {
  "mylambdaArn": {
    "Value": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": ["mylambda", "Arn"]
    }
  }
}
```

There's no way to get a list of all Lambda ARNs directly.  However, you could create a list ahead of time and pass them in as a parameter.